# Prevent links from an embeded HTML page from opening in new tabs

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a website where you can browse pages with a chat bar on the side.

I'm using an embed tag to embed another site inside the page with the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <style>
      #layout div {
      display: inline;
      width: 100%;
      }
   </style>
   <head>
      <title>Apswil's page</title>
   </head>
   <body style="background-color:black;">
      <div id="layout">
         <div>
            <iframe src="https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.kiwiirc.com/?&theme=cli#CHATNAME" style="border:0; width:19%; height:1038px;"></iframe>
         </div>
         <div>


            <!--  HERE IS THE EMBEDED WEBSITE CODE  -->
            <embed type="text/html" src="EMBEDED WEBSITE" width="79%" height="1038">


         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The problem I'm having is that when you click links inside of the embedded webpage, they open in new tabs through the use of the target tag EX. `<a href="..." target="_blank">`.

Is there any way I can prevent links inside the embedded page from opening in new tabs?

such as somehow removing the target tag when it's loading or overriding its value somehow.

I'm rather new to HTML so any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible to control this, as the iframe have it's own code and works on a different domain and you cannot control its anchor tag

Comment: You, can try using some third party apps which provide you chat functionality using some API